# AWS EBS Volumes and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a couple of questions that I hope someone will help with:

1. Can I use an EC2 instance (EBS backed) to load and run PostgreSQL DB?
2. Can I create Read Replicas for my source DB on PostgreSQL?
3. Can the Read Replica be created on the same EBS volume which houses the source DB or do I need to create the read replica on a seperate EBS volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. An EC2 instance is a general purpose computer running an x64 or x86 operating system, usually Linux or Windows, so you can run Pg on it.
2. Again, yes. An EC2 is no different to any other server in this regard, you can use any of the supported replication options including streaming replication.
3. Absolutely not, because PostgreSQL does not support shared-storage clustering. You must have *independent storage* for the read replica, using streaming replication. This is true on EC2 and everywhere else. In any case, AWS doesn't support attaching a single EC2 volume simultaneously to multiple hosts, you'd have to share it via something like drbd even if PostgreSQL did support shared storage - which it doesn't.

Where EC2 does start to differ is in performance. EC2's database performance has been .... erratic ... in my experience. Unless you use provisioned iops, in which case it's mediocre to good, but *extremely* expensive for what you get compared to real hardware. A cheap bottom of the line server with a decent SSD will thrash an expensive EC2 instance up down and sideways on most PostgreSQL workloads.

Comment: Thanks... so suppose I implement horizontal range partitioning in my postgre SQL DB server (i.e. partition the rows based on customer id) and as a result lets say I end up with 10 different EC2 instances, do I need 10 Read Replicas also or will just one read replica do? Also is a PostGre Hot Standby Server the same as a Read Replica of MySql?

Comment: @VikramChakrabarty One streaming replica can only receive changes from one master server, if that's what you're asking. You can run many streaming replicas on the same computer (use different PostgreSQL ports and data directories) if it has the performance for it, though. Depends on *why* you want the read-only replica servers. As for whether it's the same as a MySQL read replica - I don't have the detailed knowledge of MySQL's replication required to answer that and suggest you look over the PostgreSQL docs on streaming replication and PITR.

Comment: @VikramChakrabarty See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger... Your reply clarifies my concern. Well I need to partition my database based on a key range such as customer id. and then I want to create a read only replica database which will only handle read queries but no updates. This means I need one Hot Standby Server per partitioned DB. Thats what a MySql read replica is and I believe that I can achieve this same feature with Hot Standby Servers is it?

Comment: @VikramChakrabarty When you say "partition" it sounds like you're talking about horizontal partitioning, ie "sharding". Correct? If so, it's not actually per *database*; hot standbys are per database *cluster* (per database directory, in other words; a collection of databases managed by a single postmaster).

Comment: yes you are right. I am referring to Sharding. Ok... so given a sharded database lets say for example, I have one EC2 database server for customers from custID 1 to 2000 and another EC2 database server for customers 2001 to 4000 and so on... so at the end can I use just one HOT STANDBY SERVER or will I need one Hot Standby Server for each shard ??

Comment: @VikramChakrabarty This is getting off track. Please post a new question on dba.stackexchange.com that summarizes what you're trying to do, how you want the architecture to look, what you've read/tried, etc, and link to it here.